# OpenCV How to reconnect line that has blank or curvature in the middle

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

How to reconnect between line that has a curvature or blank in the middle of it.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCMxU.png)

I'm using HoughLinesP to get the line. I'm trying to reconnect line inside green circle because the line still has another line on the other side. can anyone help me or just give me a direction to solve it.Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the [maxLineGap](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghlinesp) parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to apply [morphology operations](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/dbe/tutorial_opening_closing_hats.html). What you can do with them is to fill holes inside objects or smooth borders. In your case, `closing` might be helpful:
[closing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qS0Al.png)